# How to add songs to my templates in views

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views

if i post a song from my admin panel, i want the list of song to appear in the templates, i already created a models that allow me to post it, but i don't know how to create a views that allowed the song to appear in the templates, please how can i do this ?

this is my empty views
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Audio

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

this is my models.py i created
models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Audio(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='file')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass a queryset of `Audio` objects to the template:

```
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {'songs': Audio.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

in the template we can enumerate over the songs:

```
{% for audio in songs %}
    {{ audio.book_title }} by {{ audio.artist }} </br>
{% endfor %}
```